# Npgsql library breaks Microsoft TestServer

Tags: c#, npgsql

I have some tests, which use Microsoft TestServer (Microsoft.Owin.Testing v4.0.0).  I have added a reference to Npgsql (v.4.0.0) and it suddenly breaks my test.

I have recreated this behaviour with a minimal test project.  Here is my test code:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var server = TestServer.Create(app =>
        {
            app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world using OWIN TestServer");
            });
        }))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = server.HttpClient.GetAsync("/").Result;
        }
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer.get_HttpClient()'.
at Test.Class1.Test()
```

If I remove Npgsql it doesn't fix it, although it was working before I added it in the first place. I am using Nuget to add the dependencies.

Comment: I've answered my own question because I've found a workaround, but there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use v3.2.7 of Npgsql and this fixes the problem.